# Background url() in CSS does not display image but <img src> in html makes it appear?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a html document with an inline styling in it : Here's :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f80e5e22d4148f218a2d

When I try to apply image by using Background url() then the image is not showing. Even if I try adding '../' before the path's 'images' folder or when I insert " ''  " in the beginning and end of the path inside the oval brackets.

The folder structure is as follows : index.html resides with two other folders 'stylesheets' and 'images'. The content from 'stylesheets' folder is default folder that comes with skeleton html5 boilerplate and it's stylesheets will be merged into inline styling of the html document. Inside 'images' folder there is a only one file right now called 'logo.jpg'. When I try adding the image as background by giving a 'logo' class background:url() then the image does not want to show up in Mozilla firefox and other browsers. However, when I add 'src' attribute to  tag inside html document and specify the path exactly the same way as in CSS styling then the image appears. Can someone explain to me why the image does not show up when I'm trying to add it through CSS ?

Comment: Use Firebug for Firefox, the net tab in particular, to see if the image is downloaded. If not the path is probably wrong. Keep in mind in CSS, a relative path is relative to the CSS document, not necessarily the HTML document.

Comment: On a side note, it is better to include your code in the question, preferably the minimum required to replicate the problem.

Comment: I was doing that already. Unfortunately I'm opening index.html on a localhost and upon clicking 'net' tab it does not show any info in it. I was already trying '../' etc. but without a luck

Comment: Weird, the net tab has always worked for me under local host. Try refreshing the page once the net tab is open

Comment: Still nothing. Same with the default Mozilla Firefox developer tools.

Comment: Perhaps try chrome and their dev tools, also try an absolute or root relative path to check. Inspecting the element with the various tools should also shed some light. It will how if the style is applied correctly and also show if the image is found.

Comment: Final test, inline style for the background and see if that works. Work backwards from there if it does

Comment: Chrome is bugging on my computer for whoknowswhat reason. It's extremely slow even after cleaning registry and re-installation. I'm running on Windows 8.1. Please notice that 'body' element also doesn't want to work with background url()

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example, preferably in the question itself, instead of something that is a complete page.

Answer (score 0):

By they way... if it has no src attribute, does the browser even render a height and width?

And don't use an img tag, but another tag if you dont use the src attribute... and then apply the css background. Same thing like

```
<a class="foo" target="_blank">link</a>
```

if it has no href attribute the element is not valid, and you get strange behaviour sometimes.

Comment: But why it would be a problem ? I'm specifying an element <img> which has a class of 'logo'. The class is applying all other styling and provides source of the image in background url attribute. I wanted the syntax to be semantic thus I'm trying to use attributes that correspond the best to what I want to appear on the page.

Comment: If you want semantic, then you want your logo to be crawled right? Then you just use <img src="logo.png" />, otherwise it's just another element with a background on it...

Comment: have u used "url" instead of source in background property? remeber that background image and img source are two different image. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Linking your images from CSS takes different wording than your html file.

Say this is our file tree

```
    BIGFOLDER
-public
  -app.css
-images
  -targetImage.jpg
-views
  -index.html
```

Linking from index.html

```
<img src="../images/targetImage.jpg">
```

You use "../" to go up a directory, or "././" Same thing.

Linking from app.css

```
background: url("images/targetImage.jpg");
```

The reason is that it's appending the root directory with that url, so it would be www.yoursite.com/images/targetImage.jpg

This stuff is confusing at first, but with practice it becomes second nature :)

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url#The_url%28%29_functional_notation) `url()` is relative to the stylesheet, not the webpage, so this wouldn't necessarily work as stated with the given tree.